# Where to find an exhaustive list of methods for LangOptions

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I need to configure the invocation of a `clang::CompilerInstance` class with a `clang::LangOptions` class but I am unable to find an exhaustive list of the methods of this class.

In this link ([failing to parse C++ using llvm and clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327997/failing-to-parse-c-using-llvm-and-clang)) I have found some stuff like this for c++:

```
LangOptions &langOpts = ci.getLangOpts();
langOpts.RTTI = 1;
langOpts.Bool = 1;
langOpts.CPlusPlus11 = 1;
langOpts.GNUKeywords = 1;
langOpts.CXXExceptions = 1;
langOpts.POSIXThreads = 1;
langOpts.SpellChecking = 1;
```

Here (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/os-createcompilerllvm2/index.html?ca=drs-#list15 ) they say to use:

```
langOpts.CPlusPlus = 1;
```

I have searched in the official documentation (http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1LangOptions.html) but I didn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full list is available in [`include/clang/Basic/LangOptions.def`](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/include/clang/Basic/LangOptions.def).